# How to log-in with more rights than Admin or Bureaucrat?

Tags: mediawiki, authentication

I'm having a heck of a time with MediaWiki and an [Internal Server Error](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/95430). I'd like to log-in with more privileges than afforded by Admin and Bureaucrat in hopes of actually being able to save a page.

I am an admin on the VM that hosts the wiki. I have all the usernames and passwords at my disposal. I tried logging in with the MediaWiki user and password from `LocalSettings.php` but the log-in failed.

Is it possible to acquire more privileges than provided by Admin or Bureaucrat? If so, how do I log-in with more rights than Admin or Bureaucrat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are privileges which bureaucrats do not have by default, and it is possible to give those to them (or some other group or a specific user if you prefer), e.g.

```
$wgGroupPermissions['bureaucrat'] += array_fill_keys( $wgAvailableRights, true );
```

See [the manual](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:User_rights#Changing_group_permissions) for details.

It won't help you, though. Submitting a page edit works the same way no matter what privileges you have. You really should debug and fix your problem instead of trying to find weird workarounds.

Comment: Thanks Tgr. its easier said than done when WikiMedia and PHP refuses to log and report errors.

Comment: There is probably some problem with your configuration, such as trying to log to an invalid location. Have you looked at [Manual:How to debug](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:How_to_debug)?

Comment: Yes, we are/were working from [Manual:How to debug?](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:How_to_debug). It turned out to be a Mod Security problem. It was ignoring our configuration, and doing its own thing with logging and reporting. I can't help but wonder how many 100's of thousands of man hours have been lost because the plugins can't be bothered with honoring a configuration. For what its worth, we *thought* we ruled out Mod Security months ago by submitting and saving a page with a WikiMedia table. The table used the dashes/illegal characters that caused the problem.